# Uncomplicated Firewall blocks playing streames in VLC

Tags: vlc, ufw

Can anybody help me please how to allow IGMP protocol in UFW?
My provider streams TV signal. I have .m3u8 file as channel list. It contains items as udp://@239.1.1.42:11111.

VLC does not open the stream. When I disable the firewall, it does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IPTV it is needed to allow both UPD and IGMP protocols.

For UFW edit the /etc/ufw/before.rules file:

```
# allow IGMP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p igmp -j ACCEPT
# allow UDP - address range for individual channels
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -d 239.1.2.1/5 --dport 11111 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to configure a media server in the local net. The server application that I am using is the MediaTomb. It was the single that allowed me to make transcoding of Theora/Vorbis to MP4/mp2.

Then I will configure the `ufw` according the tips of the MediaTomb's oficial website: "[My UPnP player can not see MediaTomb, what is wrong?](http://mediatomb.cc/dokuwiki/faq:faq#my_upnp_player_can_not_see_mediatomb_what_is_wrong)". Lacks me to know the syntax.

*Ref.: [Problems allowing outgoing multicast in ufw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252101/problems-allowing-outgoing-multicast-in-ufw)*

You need to know the ports and protocols — TCP and UDP, only? — that the service uses.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Multicast:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 multicast
```

And do not forget to reconnect. That's it.